# Triggering code after the window has been shown

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk4, gtk-rs

I'm using [gtk-rs](https://gtk-rs.org/). I want to trigger some code after the window has been shown (has displayed on the screen):

```
window.connect_show(clone!(@weak window => move |_| {
    let command = format!("sleep 0.1; wmctrl -r \"CSS\" -e 1,640,100,680,768");
    println!("2");
    run_command(&command);
}));

println!("1");
window.show();
println!("3");
```

This will print: `1`, `2`, `3`. Meaning that `connect_show` is triggering right before `window.show();`

This won't let the command `wmctrl -r \"CSS\" -e 1,640,100,680,768"` reposition and resize the window. A delay is needed to accomplish that:

`"sleep 0.1; wmctrl -r \"CSS\" -e 1,640,100,680,768"`

Is there another way to make the command work without having to use `sleep 0.1`?

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f2fee2c9e8f8f0fd6d8d44ea26a6f6b2) is the whole code.

Comment: I would try connecting to the "realize" signal here, since you're really asking your window manager to reposition/resize the underlying surface

Comment: @nielsdg For some reason, if I change `connect_changed` to `connect_realize`, the `println!()` follows the same order, but the `wmctrl -r \"CSS\" -e 1,640,100,680,768` command doesn't work anymore (even with `sleep`.). https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=33edff36d1ba99a4a5db0440e9d7a663

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the `wmctrl` commands is successful if I use `glib::idle_add`:

```
window.connect_show(clone!(@weak window => move |_| {
    glib::idle_add(|| {
        // the code
    glib::Continue(false)
});
```